# Printing out the hex vale of an unsigned char array in C++

Tags: c++, string, hex, std, cout

I want to print out the `hex` value of an `unsigned char` array using the `cout` function.

The most obvious approach would be something like the following.

```
unsigned char str[] = "foo bar baz\n";

for(unsigned short int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++){
  std::cout << std::hex << str[i] << std::dec << ' ';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Suprisingly, this outputs the following string:

```
foo bar baz
```

For some reason this does not print out the proper hexadecimal value of `str`

How can I `cout` the proper `hex` value of `str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `cout` the proper hex value of an unsigned char, it will need to be converted to an integer first.

```
unsigned char str[] = "foo bar baz\n";

for(unsigned short int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++){
  std::cout << std::hex << (int) str[i] << std::dec << ' ';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Gives the following output.

```
66 6f 6f 20 62 61 72 20 62 61 7a 00
```

Which corresponds with the `hex` value of each `unsigned char` in `str`.

---

An explaination for this can be found in the following `std::hex` documentation.

> ## std::hex
>
> Sets the `basefield` format flag for the str stream to `hex`.
>
> When `basefield` is set to `hex`, **integer** values inserted into the stream are expressed in hexadecimal base (i.e., radix 16). For input streams, extracted values are also expected to be expressed in hexadecimal base when this flag is set.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/